# Can select into add a new field to the resulting table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select

I've got a SQL statement in SQL Server 2005 that looks something like this:

```
SELECT * INTO #TempTable FROM FirstTable WHERE <complex where clause>
```

What I would really, really like is to have the resulting temp table have an extra field that is essentially an integer field counting from 1 up in the order the where clause returned the records.

Is this possible?

(Essentially, I want to be able to return a subset of the records returned from the first select statement, along the lines of "lines 45 through 179".)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this, using [Row_Number](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx):

```
-- insert into temp table
SELECT *, 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SortColumn) AS SortColumn INTO #TempTable 
FROM FirstTable 
WHERE <complex where clause>

-- check the results and drop the table
SELECT * FROM #TempTable WHERE SortColumn BETWEEN 45 AND 179 ORDER BY SortColumn
DROP TABLE  #TempTable
```

Obviously you'll need to replace `SortColumn` with whatever makes sense in your case

---

**Edit:**

If you're just trying to do paging, there are lots of examples of that:

- http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2005/12/30/2652.aspx
- http://www.sqlteam.com/article/server-side-paging-using-sql-server-2005
- http://www.google.com/search?q=sql+server+2005+paging

Comment: I'd add an ORDER BY SortColumn to the end of the first statement as well, just in case.

Comment: Good point Joel. I updated it with an order by on the temp table select and added in the window criteria.

Comment: @Electrons_Ahoy: if you really only need a subset of the records, checkout the paging links I included--there are lots of ways to do this more efficiently without temp tables.

Comment: Well, that's just perfect.  I am doing paging, but (as usual) I'm just modifying an existing ginormous stored procedure, so I've inherited the temp table and associated logic. :)  Those links are fantasic, though.  Thanks a bundle.